# Copy specific numbers from one array to another

Tags: java, arrays, copy

Is there a way of copying specific numbers from one array to another?
For example:
I have an array `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`
and I want to copy odd and even numbers to separate arrays. So, the result should be
`{2, 4}, {1, 3, 5}`

Comment: Yes, there is a way. But I'm sure this wasn't your actual question. Which part of that assignment do you have problems with? Iterating over the existing array? Determining if a number is odd or even? Sorting those numbers into a new array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    int[] even = IntStream.of(array).filter(i -> i % 2 == 0).toArray();
    int[] odd = IntStream.of(array).filter(i -> i % 2 != 0).toArray();

    System.out.println("even = " + Arrays.toString(even));
    System.out.println("odd = " + Arrays.toString(odd));
}
```

output:

```
even = [2, 4]
odd = [1, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] ls={1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

List<Integer> odd=new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int l :ls) {
    if(l%2==1) {
        odd.add(l);
    }
}
System.out.println(odd);

List<Integer> even=new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int l :ls) {
    if(l%2==0) {
        even.add(l);
    }
}
System.out.println(even);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import java.util.*;

class Dragon {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] list = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

        List<Integer> oddList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> evenList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int l : list) {
            if (l % 2 == 0)
                evenList.add(l);
            else
                oddList.add(l);
        }
        System.out.println("Odd = " + oddList);
        System.out.println("Even = " + evenList);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Odd = [1, 3, 5]
Even = [2, 4]
```